# How to join multiple times on the same table with the max value for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, query-optimization

I have a table activity that has 5 fields:

```
id - numeric
user_id - numeric 
type_id - numeric
content_id - numeric
date_of_activity date
```

I need to make a query, the result of which will be 7 columns:

```
id(type1 activity),content_id(type 1) at max(date_of_activity for type 1),max(date_of_activity for type 1)content_id(type 2) at max(date_of_activity for type 2),max(date_of_activity for type 2)content_id(type 3) at max(date_of_activity for type 3),max(date_of_activity for type 3)
```

If there is no corresponding value for type_id for an user  then NULL value should be shown in corresponding column.

Example:

```
users
    user_id: 1
    user_id: 2
    user_id: 3
```

```
activities

    id: 1
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 2
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/01
    content_id: 12

    id: 2
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 3
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/01
    content_id: 102

    id: 3
    user_id: 2
    type_id: 3
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/01
    content_id: 213

    id: 4
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 2
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/02
    content_id: 13

    id: 5
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 3
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/02
    content_id: 103

    id: 6
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 1
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/03
    content_id: 1

    id: 7
    user_id: 2
    type_id: 1
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/03
    content_id: 212
    
    id: 8
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 3
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/03
    content_id: 104

    id: 8
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 3
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/04
    content_id: 105

    id: 10
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 1
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/05
    content_id: 2

    id: 11
    user_id: 1
    type_id: 3
    date_of_activity: 2021/05/05
    content_id: 106
```

the result should be:

```
id:10,
user_id:1,
type_id:1,
date_of_activity: 2021/05/05,
activity2.date_of_activity:2021/05/02,
activity2.content_id:13,
activity3.date_of_activity: 2021/05/05,
activity3.content_id:106

id:7,
user_id: 2,
type_id: 1,
date_of_activity: 2021/05/03,
content_id: 212,
activity2.date_of_activity: NULL,
activity2.content_id: NULL,
activity3.date_of_activity:2021/05/01
activity3.content_id:213
```

As you can see i retreived one activity , per activity type for each user, each activity being the most recent one, and so on for all the users...

I have a query than can retrieve the most recent activity for each user for ONE activity type :

```
SELECT
activities.*,
dDates.max
FROM activities
JOIN users on users.id = activities.user_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,max(activities.date_of_activity) FROM activities WHERE activities.type_id = 6 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL group by user_id) as dDates on activities.user_id = maxDates.user_id
WHERE activities.type_id = 6 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL AND activities.date_of_activity = dDates.max;
```

But sometimes i need to join on multiples activities as part of the same query so i'm trying to grab everything at once but i can't find a way that isn't very slow.

i've tried created a view / use "With"  for each type :

```
CREATE VIEW MostRecentType1 AS
SELECT
activities.*,
dDates.max
FROM activities
JOIN users on users.id = activities.user_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,max(activities.date_of_activity) FROM activities WHERE activities.type_id = 1 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL group by user_id) as dDates on activities.user_id = maxDates.user_id
WHERE activities.type_id = 1 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL AND activities.date_of_activity = dDates.max;
```

```
CREATE VIEW MostRecentType2 AS
SELECT
activities.*,
dDates.max
FROM activities
JOIN users on users.id = activities.user_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,max(activities.date_of_activity) FROM activities WHERE activities.type_id = 1 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL group by user_id) as dDates on activities.user_id = maxDates.user_id
WHERE activities.type_id = 1 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL AND activities.date_of_activity = dDates.max;
```

and then a finally a left join on the views

```
SELECT
activities.*,
dDates.max,
type2.date_of_activity as "type2.date_of_activity as",
type2.content_id as "type2.content_id",
type3.date_of_activity as "type3.date_of_activity" ,
type3.content_id as "type3.content_id" ,
FROM activities
JOIN users on users.id = activities.user_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,max(activities.date_of_activity) FROM activities WHERE activities.type_id = 1 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL group by user_id) as dDates on activities.user_id = maxDates.user_id
LEFT JOIN MostRecentType2 as type2 on activities.user_id = type2.user_id
LEFT JOIN MostRecentType3 as type3 on activities.user_id = type3.user_id
WHERE activities.type_id = 1 AND activities.deleted_at IS NULL AND activities.date_of_activity = dDates.max;
```

But this doesn't scale well at all.

On my mostly empty activities table if i just perform the 1st query alone it will take 4ms, but once i add the first "MostRecentType2" join it jumps
to 40ms, then MostRecentType3 go to 80 ms and keeps on incrementing this way and in some case i need lots of joins.

Any ideas on how to (better) make that query  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `DISTINCT ON` to get the most recent row for each type for each user.  Then just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(date_of_activity) FILTER (WHERE type_id = 1) as date_1,
       MAX(content_id) FILTER (WHERE type_id = 1) as content_1,
       MAX(date_of_activity) FILTER (WHERE type_id = 2) as date_2,
       MAX(content_id) FILTER (WHERE type_id = 2) as content_2,
       MAX(date_of_activity) FILTER (WHERE type_id = 3) as date_3,
       MAX(content_id) FILTER (WHERE type_id = 3) as content_3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, type_id) a.*
      FROM activities a
      WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL
      ORDER BY user_id, type_id, date_of_activity DESC
     ) a
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: @joinjohn . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: only issue with this query is that i gives me the whole set of activity every time and not the type that is searched for. In my example there is always one " main " activity and then this activity is joined onto the rest. " - the output of my example is the list of activity of type "1" at max date and afterwards i do the join

Comment: yes i spoke to soon and i just encountered and issue with it :(

Comment: @joinjohn . . . You can add a `where` clause to filter on the activities you care about.  That filtering does not seem to be an important part of the question you asked.

Comment: I've tried the where clause, but it makes the rest of the query not work as it will filters all the activities before the max is calculated. if i do `WHERE a.type_id = 6` the data for content_2 , content_3, date_2 , date_3 , etc... will always be NULL unlike my example

Comment: I'm thinking of using your query as left join on my query so that i can be done in one " subquery join " instead of N